# Return 0 when a value of a cell is negative

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that uses this function:

```
=SUM(E:E) - SUM(C:C)
```

It adds up all the values of column E and column C and them subtracts the difference.  I would like to be able to return a 0 if the difference is negative.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
=MAX(SUM(E:E) - SUM(C:C),0)
```

The MAX function receives a list values
eg. MAX(1, 2, 3, 4) would give 4
so if you give it 0 then it will return 0 since it's higher than the negative result

Answer (score 3):

`IF((SUM(E:E) - SUM(C:C))< 0,0,SUM(E:E) - SUM(C:C))`

Answer (score 2):

Possible without changing the existing formula but with formatting such as:

```
#.00;"0";0
```

This differs from a formula approach such as `=MAX(SUM(E:E)-SUM(C:C),0)` because adding a number to the output of that formula will give as a result the added number, where `SUM(C:C)` is greater than `SUM(E:E)`. Adding the same addend to `=SUM(E:E)-SUM(C:C)` where `SUM(C:C)` is greater than `SUM(E:E)` will not give the addend as the result, except when the added is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I took another route - I just copied the entire column to another column to the far right, and then referenced that column for my formulas in the column I want to edit.
When you're finished, "hide" the copied column (click on the column menu and there is a "hide" option), but DO NOT delete it, because then your formulas will not work.